# Could we use NE 555 Timer for industrial magnetic proximity switching circuit?

Tags: electrical-engineering, automotive-engineering, sensors, magnets

I actually need a magnetic proximity switching circuit such that
In the case of water in fuel sensor, whenever the water level in water in fuel sensor increases the magnetic float shall move and come in forward in the proximity of hall sensor which in turn switches the magnetic reed position and the output has to given to the ECU is this concept correct. Can we do this with a timer circuit? Will timer circuit do the purpose? Does timer circuit need any extra protection circuit when used in industrial applications?

[image]

Comment: Better on the electrical stack?

Comment: As Mile says: [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)